# Why PartialView method always returns null view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a following controller method

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult Result(List<Models.Domain> domains)
    {
        return PartialView(domains);
    }
```

Which I call from anther controller method and in the result I always get a null view.

I've tried to specify full path, relative path, make asp mvc to find it with the above described code, put there some mambo jambo - the result is always the same - null view, no error or exceptions.

Comment: What do you mean *I call from anther controller method*.. this method should be called from views, not controllers.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I need to get the view's generated code somehow and use it in another controller method

Comment: You should not mix view and controller logic, if you want to reuse the partial view just call - `@Html.Action("Result", domains)`  or `@{ Html.RenderAction("Result", domains);  }`in the required view, partial will be rendered there